# ImageFilter.blur (BackdropFilter) Not working | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

When i use BackdropFilter in Container's child, Phone screen going color black. and when i remove that coding. It shows background image. what's going wrong?

I want to blur my background image of app. No errors shows. but final render is black screen. no any image

```
Stack(
        children: [
        //background image here with blur
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/u2.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: 10,
              sigmaY: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ),
],),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `BackdropFilter` child

```dart
Positioned.fill(
  child: Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/u2.jpg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 10,
        sigmaY: 10,
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[image]

Test scaffold

```dart
 return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/img.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: BackdropFilter(
                    filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                      sigmaX: 10,
                      sigmaY: 10,
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: It also not working. this try, showing image without blur

Comment: need to provide size, try update one

Comment: Did, like this   
BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 10,
            sigmaY: 10,
          ),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/u2.jpg'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

Comment: On the parent widget. of Stack, I will share the full scaffold

Comment: Glad to help. more about [BackdropFilter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageFiltered() widget instead of BackDropFilter()